# Angular 2: Uncaught Error: Illegal HTML attribute name: *ngfor

Tags: node.js, meteor, angular, ngfor

I have angular 2 running inside of meteor . I have been following a tutorial on it and am stuck on this step:

http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/dynamic-template

I can't seem to figure out why the app.component.html file that references the *ngfor is throwing that error because all the angular &  angular2-meteor npm packages are installed in my node_modules directory. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-meteor-base",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha",
    "test:ci": "meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "angular2-meteor": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "0.6.0",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "0.1.1",
    "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "0.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  }
}
```

Here is the app.component.html:

```
<head>
  <title>tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Price Compare!</h1>

  <ul>
    <li>
        <span>Dubstep-Free Zone</span>
        <p>
        Can we please just for an evening not listen to dubstep.
        </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>All dubstep all the time</span>
        <p>
        Get it on!
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let party of parties">
      {{party.name}}
      <p>{{party.description}}</p>
      <p>{{party.location}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


</body>
```

Here is the app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import template from './app.component.html';




@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template
})

export class AppComponent {
  parties: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.parties = [
      {'name': 'Dubstep-Free Zone',
        'description': 'Can we please just for an evening not listen to dubstep.',
        'location': 'Palo Alto'
      },
      {'name': 'All dubstep all the time',
        'description': 'Get it on!',
        'location': 'Palo Alto'
      },
      {'name': 'Savage lounging',
        'description': 'Leisure suit required. And only fiercest manners.',
        'location': 'San Francisco'
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

here is my index.html:

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  <app> </app>
</body>
```

here is my main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Console output:

[image]

I believe my files match the tutorial exactly, but maybe I'm just not seeing something thats obvious...

UPDATE 1:
I just deleted my node_modules directory and re-ran meteor npm install then re-copied all files content in the client folder from the tutorial's git repo and still does not work. Its still not recognizing the *ngFor tag which tells me somehow my meteor project is not recognizing angular OR possibly its my node install and OS browser combo. I'm on Windows 7 using Chrome, node version: v6.3.1

UPDATE 2:
I think possibly something @neeraj mentioned I should resolve first ... that was that my app.component.html file should not have head or body tags . I think that is right because meteor adds your html files content to its "master" html file so therefore no need for the head and body tags. HOWEVER, when I omit the head and body tags in my app.component.html file this error is thrown:

```
While processing files with templating (for target web.browser):
client/app.component.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
```

Comment: Anyone have a clue?

Comment: if thats the correct spelling, ur syntax is off. its camelcase. *ngFor

Comment: Actually,  in the code it's correct but in the the console error output  it's as I stated in the question detail.

Comment: Do you import the `BrowserModule` in `@NgModule(...) export class AppComponent {}`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  "Do you import the BrowserModule in @NgModule(...)"       ----- where is that supposed to be?

Comment: Does this mean you don't use `@NgModule()` in your code? It was introduced with RC.5 and is not yet mandatory. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html. How do you bootstrap Angular?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm using meteor and following the tutorial here: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/dynamic-template

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's special about using Meteor or not.

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my post "I think possibly something @neeraj mentioned I should resolve first ... that was that my app.component.html file should not have head or body tags"

Once I resolved that problem all else seemed to fall into place ---- the way I resolved it was to clone the tutorial from git and start again from step 1.